# Issue in iOS 9 when I try to open some application

Tags: ios, itunes

I have my application developed in Objective-C running on iOS 9 and before the update to 9.0.2, my app worked normally.

**Update 20/10**

I tried many times, but still doesn't work, 
I need to call the url:

```
cielomobile://pagar?urlCallback=appcliente://retornopagamento
```

but I am aways receive the message:

```
- error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cielomobile
```

This is my info.plist:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use URL schemes. Try loading the URL `fb://` and watch facebook open or `tel://` and watch the phone app open.

App2 needs to have a `URL Scheme` assigned in its' `info.plist`

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

---

Then, if you're iOS9+, in info.plist add the following dictionary:
[image]

Comment: Please, see my update

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira updated

Comment: `NSAppTransportSecurity` concerns the use of TLS and encryption over HTTP connections.  This is unrelated to URL schemes and doesn't need to be set here.  Also, Apple has specifically recommended against setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`  except as a last resort.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Answer (score 3):

Apple made some changes to the handling of URL schemes in iOS 9 for security reasons:

http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

If you are calling `canOpenURL` to check for the presence of the other application, starting with iOS9 you'll need to supply a whitelist of URLs your app expects to query:

> "Up until iOS 9, apps have been able to call these methods (`openURL` and `canOpenURL`) on any
>   arbitrary URLs. Starting on iOS 9, apps will have to declare what URL
>   schemes they would like to be able to check for and open in the
>   configuration files of the app as it is submitted to Apple. This is
>   essentially a whitelist that can only be changed or added to by
>   submitting an update to Apple."

Try adding this to your info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>cielomobile</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Please, see my update.